# update strategy expression DD_UPDATE AND (condition)

Tags: informatica

What this means? 
DD_UPDATE and ($$export_agreement =0 OR $$export_agreement =1)

i can't find anything regarding the "and" condition.

thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DD_UPDATE, DD_INSERT, ... are only readable names for constants used by Update Strategy :

```
DD_INSERT   0
DD_UPDATE   1
DD_DELETE   2
DD_REJECT   3
```

So the Update Strategy simply uses the return value of the expression, whatever is returned.

For this example, suppose different values of `$$export_agreement` :

- If `$$export_agreement` is `0`, the return value is `1`, which means Update.
- If `$$export_agreement` is `1`, the return value is `1`, which means Update.
- If `$$export_agreement` is `2`, the return value is `0`, which means Insert.

I don't know if it's what was intended, but I would suggest you write it in a more explicit way :

```
iif( $$export_agreement =0 OR $$export_agreement =1, DD_UPDATE, DD_INSERT)
```